# PartialView is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

The controller is in /Areas/ShoppingCart/Controllers/

I've tried to let the controller return the PartialView which in /Views/Shared folder.

The Code as follows:

```
namespace MVCIIITourism.Areas.shoppingcart.Controllers
{
  public class CartController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult GetCart()
    {
      return PartialView("../../Shared/Views_Cartpatail.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
      var currentCart = Operation.GetCurrentCart();
      currentCart.AddProduct(id);
      return PartialView("../../Shared/Views_Cartpatail.cshtml");
    }
  }
}
```

But the chrome shows the error message that is

> Not Found PartialView in /Areas/ShoppingCart/Controllers/

How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your partial is in the shared folder you don`t have to pass the entire path

Shared folder it`s access by all controllers

Simple use:

```
return PartialView("Views_Cartpatail.cshtml");
```